# Alterar o valor do botão sem mostrar alerta

Tags: javascript, html5

Quero alterar valor do botão sempre com -1, sem mostrar alerta.

Segue código:

```
<button  onclick="alert(this.value);this.value -= 1;" value="200">200</button>
```

Comment: O que é 200 ? Tente explicar melhor.

Comment: Por favor, elabore melhor a sua pergunta e se possível insira o código que está utilizando.

Comment: Não coloque no comentário. Coloque na pergunta.

Comment: Nao to conseguindo colocar na pergunta ta bugado!

Comment: @JDchaves, Voce quer diminuir o botão do alerta ?

Comment: Não eu quero tirar o alerta e diminuir os valores sem que o alerta apareça!

Comment: @JDchaves, Você quer alterar o valor sem mostrar alerta ?

Comment: Isso mesmo matheus!

Comment: @JDchaves olha na minha resposta.

Comment: Ok vou ver aqui!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que o alerta não apareça, basta retirar a chamada de `alert()`.

Já para atualizar o **texto** do botão (que não é o mesmo que o atributo `value`), você deve atualizar também a propriedade `innerHTML`:

```js
function diminuiValor(botao) {
    // diminui o "value"
    botao.value -= 1;
    // atualiza o texto do botão para ser o mesmo que o value
    botao.innerHTML = botao.value;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="diminuiValor(this);" value="200">200</button>
```

Ou, de forma mais direta (sem criar uma `function`):

```html
<button onclick="this.value -= 1; this.innerHTML = this.value;" value="200">200</button>
```

Resumindo, `this.value -= 1` diminui o valor que foi definido no atributo `value="200"`, enquanto o `innerHTML` atualiza o texto do botão. Nos exemplos acima estou assumindo que você quer mudar ambos (pois é o que faz mais sentido pra mim).

Comment: Mano obrigado! Era isso mesmo que eu queria! Tmj valeu❤

Answer (score 0):

Veja o exemplo que você quer:

```js
$("#id_do_botao").click(function() {
  var valor = this.value -= 1;
  $(this).text(valor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="id_do_botao" value="200">200</button>
```

Comment: Matheus tipo asim,eu quero que o valor diminua ao clicar em cima do botao certo? Então mais eu não quero que fique aparecendo esse alert eu queria que o valor diminuice em cima do botão mesmo ou em baixo tendeu?

Comment: @JDchaves meu código está fazendo oque ? Clica executar e testa.

Comment: rsrsrs.. acho que ele não foi com a sua cara.

Comment: Eu testei mano mais não funcionou!

Comment: @LeAndrade pois é kkk

Comment: @MatheusMiranda acho pq vc fez com jQuery, aí não funcionou lá pra ele.

Comment: Kkkk nao mano nada disso desculpa mano eu testei mais nao funcionou!

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda matheus!!❤